# configurator.embsetupopendsfailed, refer to install.log openam installation

Tags: tomcat7, openam

I'am facing the following error in installing OpenAM via Web GUI.

> configurator.embsetupopendsfailed, refer to install.log under
>   /usr/share/tomcat7/openam for more information.

In `install.log` it says:

> AMSetupServlet.processRequest:
>   errorcom.sun.identity.setup.ConfiguratorException:
>   configurator.embsetupopendsfailed

I have searched a lot for the solution for this, but didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar situation. I did the following to resolve this

1. On my windows machine, I modified the file under %system32%/drivers/etc/hosts to include "openam.example.com" and pointed this host to the IP of my Ubuntu server where I installed OpenAM.
2. On my Ubuntu machine, changed the hosts file in /etc/hosts. Here, I again added entry for "openam.example.com" and pointed it to the localhost IP.

After doing the above steps, I stopped tomcat and started it again. You might be prompted to cleanup the existing configuration, just follow the instructions in their installation guide for this particular step and then you should be good to go!

**Update:**

I was able to find the root cause of this issue. Looks like for some reason, the "hostname -A" command was returning a blank string and not a FQDN on my Amazon EC2 instance. On researching a bit more, I found that there was no public DNS assigned to my EC2 instance. Hence, I ended up updating the /etc/hostname file with the FQDN and rebooting the instance. The installation should go through with this fix.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i had tried adding FQDN in /etc/hosts already, but your answer triggered it again. so rolled out a new instance and try the installation and it bring me success at the first attempt. So i thought may be that was the post installation or some kind of cache on server that was causing the issue and i was not able to remove that completely. Anyway it's done now, Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: I think you are right, I also faced the same situation today and after I cleared the openam directory from tomcat webapps and restarted tomcat, this issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue in 3 steps.

1. Added an entry for openam.example.com pointing to localhost IP address in `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1   openam.example.com
```

2. I changed JDK to Oracle® JDK v1.8 from Open JDK v8u292. (For more info: goto this [link](https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/book/b91758479#a45520421))
3. Restart the machine and the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. In my case, OpenAM was in a different machine. I thought OpenAM will not need host mapping of itself. But it does.

I put same host mapping in both sides and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the title, and it looks like it was because of OpenJDK.  I switched to Oracle Java 11, and it worked fine.